# How to automatically sort methods by order they are used in class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style

Imagine a following public method:

```
public void DoSomethingWithInput(Input input)
{
    if (IsInputNice(input))
    {
        DoNiceThingsWithInput(input);
    }
    else if (IsInputUgly(input))
    {
        DoUglyThingsWithInput(input);
    }
    else
    {
        HandleUnknownInput(input);
    }
}
```

Now, provided all methods used inside are private, I would like to be able to sort them so that they appear *beneath* the `DoSomethingWithInput` method in the order they are used:

```
private bool IsInputNice(Input input) { }
private void DoNiceThingsWithInput(Input input) { }
private bool IsInputUgly(Input input) { }
private void DoUglyThingsWithInput(Input input) { }
private void HandleUnknownInput(Input input) { }
```

In other words, I want to be able to sort all methods by access modifier first and usage order second. Is there a way to achieve this automatically (e.g. by some Visual Studio extension)?

Thank you!

Comment: You can make your own add on, but I'm pretty sure there is no out of the box feature that does this.

Comment: Postsharp may force this behaviour, but does not do this automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/docs/2007/05/introduction.html) can help you?

"Regionerate lets you define regions in your code and determine the way members (fields, methods, properties etc.) should be placed inside them."